# My function does not return a value when I use the Ganache provider

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache

When I deploy the smart contract in the Remix VM my function returns a random number but when I use the Ganache provider my function returns nothing.

````
    // Initializing the state variable
    uint randNonce = 0;
    
    // Defining a function to generate a random number
    function randMod() public
    returns(uint, string memory) {
        // increase nonce
        randNonce++; 
    return (uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp,randNonce))) % 100, "Hi random number" );
    }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a bit misleading from Remix.

The reason is that in a real-world blockchain network, that `randMod` function would not return anything to the client. That is because the `randMod` function is non-`view`/non-`pure`. This means that the `randMod` function modifies the state of the contract.

For a function call to modify the state of a contract, you need to sign a transaction and broadcast it to the network, it will reach a miner/validator, and it will be executed and included in a block. All this will happen asynchronously, so you can't expect the response from a non-`view` or non-`pure` function because you don't know when it will be executed and included in a block.

So, since Remix's provider is their own local blockchain implementation, they return the value right away when your transaction is "mined". This is misleading because that will not happen in the real world.

Is well known that when you call a contract function that modifies the state and you want the result to get back to you, the contract function needs to emit an event with the data that you are expecting, you subscribe to that event using something like `web3js` or `ethersjs`, and when your transaction is executed and included in a block, you will get notified when the event is emitted and you can get the data from the event.

If you call a `pure` or `view` function, you can expect the value right away, because the transaction will not be broadcasted or included in a block, just one node will execute the function and return the value right away for you, synchronously.

I replied to a similar question yesterday and put more details and code examples, if you want to take a look at that: [Return data using EVM memory within a callback function to Web3/Front-end](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136121/return-data-using-evm-memory-within-a-callback-function-to-web3-front-end/136136#136136)